# HTTP Request header

Tags: php, simplexml

I am familiar with displaying items from and XML feed using PHP, but an API I have just started working on requires me to include the HTTP Request header...

```
   Feed-Auth => myPassword
```

How do I include a HTTP Request Header?

Answer (score 1):

```
header("Feed-Auth:".$myPassword);
```

If you are hitting the API using something like `curl` or `soap`, they have their own mechanisms for setting headers.

Curl:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Feed-Auth:'.$myPassword));
```

SOAP

```
  $header = array('Feed-Auth'=>$myPassword);
  $soapHeader = new SoapHeader('NAMESPACE','Header',$header,false);
  $client->__setSoapHeaders($oapHeader);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, simplexml doesn't have such a mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to load the document in another way and use `simplexml_load_string()`:

```
$body = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'header' => 'Feed-Auth: myPassword',
    ),
)));

$doc = simplexml_load_string($body);
```

Comment: So this is my current code..

    <?php
    $theurl = 'http://www.thesite.co.uk/feedurl.xml';
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($theurl);
        $result = $xml->xpath("/Search/Match/");
        foreach ($result as $item) { 
        echo $item->SubItem;
        } ?>

Can that be easily adapted?

Comment: Jack, in your example above... $url ... would that be the feed URL?

Comment: @user2227359 You're welcome; since you're new here, read the [about] section to learn how to accept answers.